# set my state with collection_select with pluginaweek/state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

How do I create a collecton_select drop down to set the state of a resource in a form?

right now I have

```
<%= f.collection_select :state, Ticket.state.all, :event, :state_name_humanize, :prompt => true %>
```

(could pluginaweek make a 'getting started with state_machine' tutorial, I am really hot on using it, but I am a nube . . .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [example](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/tree/master/examples/rails-rest) a collection select should look like this: `<%= f.collection_select :access_state_event, @user.access_state_transitions, :event, :human_event, :include_blank => "don't change" %>`

Would also like to see a simple example/tutorial for active record